# Ubuntu terminal is not showing anything

Tags: freeze

My Ubuntu machine terminal is not showing anything. I'm not able to write anything in it. I's showing only the cursor. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Was it like this when you installed Ubuntu, or did this happen after you did some specific action? If yes, tell what you did please.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have installed npm . that's it. after that its not working.

Comment: So next question would be - how did you install npm? Which exact commands did you run?